# VBA "LastRow" pasting on top of eachother?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks here, and I've named each of the worksheets I'm working on: `wsINPUTS` and `wsFILLS`. I'm trying to copy values from `wsFILLS` onto `wsINPUTS` only if there is a value >0 in a particular cell. I want to copy onto `wsINPUTS` starting on `A2` and then pasting any other values directly below the previous pasted values.

Right now, my code is  copying the data and pasting it in the `INPUTS` worksheet on top of each other in `A2` instead of pasting directly below it. Help!

```
With wsINPUTS
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
End With

    If wsFILLS.Range("C8") > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B4:C9").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & LastRow))

    If wsFILLS.Range("C16").Value > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B11:C16").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & LastRow))

    If wsFILLS.Range("C23").Value > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B18:C23").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & LastRow))
```

Comment: Are you asking how to update `LastRow` after each copy?

Comment: You will need to put `LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` before each use of last row to keep getting new last rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pasting data from different points directly after each other that will naturally change the last row after each copy, so you have to account for that in the code.

Try something like the below instead.

```
If wsFILLS.Range("C8") > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B4:C9").Copy wsINPUTS.Range("A" & wsInputs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

If wsFILLS.Range("C16").Value > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B11:C16").Copy wsINPUTS.Range("A" & wsInputs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

If wsFILLS.Range("C23").Value > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B18:C23").Copy wsINPUTS.Range("A" & & wsInputs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you wrote and putting into a more compact form that recalculates the lastrow variable each time it's needed.

```
If wsFILLS.Range("C8") > 0 Then wsFILLS.Range("B4:C9").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & wsINPUTS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1))

If wsFILLS.Range("C16").Value > 0 Then  wsFILLS.Range("B11:C16").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & wsINPUTS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1))

If wsFILLS.Range("C23").Value > 0 Then  wsFILLS.Range("B18:C23").Copy (wsINPUTS.Range("A" & wsINPUTS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1))
```